# Can I keep the tooltip open when the user is using a control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I want to display the value of a slider as the user moves the slider up and down. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you can do this

AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight"

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a Custom ToolTip using Popup. You can update the Popup position as and when the slider moves. Also, this kind of tooltips gives nice UX feedback to the user.

Comment: I would use this approach if you need custom formatting on the Popup. If you just need the value displayed then use the AutoToolTip.